# Settings up Team Services build to deploy to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a build in Team Services (Visual Studio Online) but am having a few issues.

My first step is to create a new build and I've selected the template *Deployment -> Azure Web App*

Then in the build step for Azure Deployment I need to select my Azure subscription. This list is currently empty so I select *Manage* to add a new one.

Following the instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/) I try to add a new endpoint but it says to select the one called 'Azure' but in my list I've got 'Azure Classic' and 'Azure Resource Manager'. Which one should I use?

I've tried 'Azure Resource Manager' and used the details to generate service key etc using the Powershell script as said in the previous link. Now the status just stay at 'Connecting to service using Service Principal' and is not selectable in the list.

How do I get Team Services to see my Azure subscription?

I must say, I've found the documentation for this a bit lacking in that a lot of the Microsoft sites still use the classic portal or older versions for the sites.

Comment: Sorry, log didn't come out very readable. Is there a better way of adding it? It should have line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the end of your question, one of the reasons of that is that some functionality is not available yet on the new portal. As far as i know, all of the functionality should migrate to the new portal in a future.

For Azure Web App, please add the New Service Endpoint using classic mode (and i prefer to do that using certificate - very simple). Then, when adding the web site as the build step (for example), select your added subscription and you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alex that did help get connected but it's not actually doing anything (I've updated my question with the deploy log). Am I missing something else?

Comment: Let's chat about that issue.

Comment: @ADringer http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111355/tfsazurewebapp could you join?

Comment: Sorry only just saw this, I've joined it now

Comment: Just a bit of additional information that as of the time of this comment my deployments done through Team Services of a build I created didn't show up in the Audit Log or Deployment section of the Azure Portal. It can be seen at https://youwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments